PleaseConformOnePass - Adjusting print commands & how to stop the program from crashing on an empty list
I am currently working through Chapter 1 Srini Devadas' 'Programming for the Puzzled' book where he talks through the PleaseConform and the PleaseConformOnePass program.
He's set up some exercises at the end of the chapter where he wants certain adjustments to be made on the existing code. I'm particularly stuck with the second exercise where it states the following:
Modify pleaseConformOnePass to print more natural commands and ensure that it does not crash on an empty list
Hint, you will need to remember the beginning of the interal (and not print on line 6)
The natural commands he states would be something like this:
'People in positions 2 through 4 flip your caps!'
'People in positions 6 through 8 flip your caps!'
'Person at position 11 flip your cap!
The code he has demonstrated in Chapter 1 is:
 def pleaseConformOnePass(caps):
    caps = caps + [caps[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(caps)):
        if caps[i] != caps[i - 1]:
            if caps[i] != caps[0]:
                print(f"People in positions {i}", end="")
            else:
                print(f" through {i-1}, please flip your caps!")

I believe it's line 2 that is causing the program to crash when 'caps' is an empty list (caps[0] has no value/element therefore the program throws an error) but removing the caps[0] is producing in correct results.
The print statements I'm completey stuck on and have no idea on how to adjust them.

I implemented empty list management with an if-statement and I did that to remember the beginning of the interal whit the variable 'start_interval'.
To improve the natural language I used, two version of the sentence: Person at position 1, please flip your cap! and People in positions 5 through 6, please flip your caps!
Below the code:
def pleaseConformOnePass(caps):

if caps:
    start_interval = None
    caps +=  [caps[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(caps)):

        if caps[i] != caps[0]:
            
            if start_interval is None:
                start_interval = i
                
        if start_interval not in [None, i] and caps[i] != caps[i-1]:
            if i-1 == start_interval:
                print(f"Person at position {start_interval}, please flip your cap!")
            else: 
                print(f"People in positions {start_interval} through {i-1}, please flip your caps!")
            start_interval = None

# Example usage:
caps_list = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
pleaseConformOnePass(caps_list)

I hope I understood the request correctly.
